# Editing in Propertygrid not enabled from Expander

Tags: c#, collections, editor, propertygrid, expander

I have a list in Propertygrid that opens by expander. I created it using the following site:
**[Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)**

I added this Editor Type to cancel the `Collection Editor`:

```
class MyEditor: UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[Editor(typeof(MyEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public class MyCollection : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{...}
```

The problem is you can not edit the values ​​in the collection via the Expander.

I have two questions:

1. Why the Expander appears as disable editing?
2. How can I allow the user to edit via Expander?

Comment: What do your custom `PropertyDescriptor` implementations look like? By "expander", do you mean the `[+]` editing inside the grid? or the `[…]` editor? In particular, what *converter* does the custom property descriptor return per-object?

Comment: @MarcGravell. `PropertyDescriptor` look like the `PropertyDescriptor` site. By "expander" I mean `[+]`, `[...]`= collection editor I remove it by `MyEditor.cs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why you can not edit,

because each value in a list is an `object` you can not edit it,

even though I put in `GetValue` one value from the object.